# Creating a "trusted" xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I created an xml file in C#, but there is an annoying thing that when i open the file there is a yellow message from windows on the top of the window that says its trying to protect me, and ask me if i trust this file. is there a way to create the file so the message won't show up?

Comment: can u post the xml if it is small enough??

Comment: what?? how it would help? the XML is OK, but the message allway shows. try it yourself and create xml file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to digitally sign the XML document if you want to get the trusted behavior out of it (i.e. no yellow warning bar). Below is how to do that (you'll need a digital certificate from a trusted root authority though, like Verisign).

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745.aspx
- http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/257599.aspx

**Edit**: If you don't have a signing certificate from Verising etc. you can use a workaround like this:

> go into Internet Options > Advanced
>   then down to the Security section, and
>   tick the box for "Allow active content
>   to run in files on My Computer*"

Here is the source: http://www.leonmeijer.nl/archive/2008/04/27/106.aspx

Comment: This example reads xml. i want to create it, and open it by double click.

Comment: To sign it, you first create an xml document, than you read it to get a hash and then you sign that hash with your digital certificate. Then you can double click to one the file and it won't display the yellow bar. If this is complicated, you can always use the workaround but that works only for your computer, not clients.

Comment: Reposting a positive input that I got from Maarten via e-mail here: "It may be rather simple (for you and me) to get XML verify to return true. But the problem is that the "true" may not mean much. The problem is that you cannot trust the XML file itself for verification.
So you have to make sure that all the algorithms specified are correct. Moreover, you must make sure that the data you are verifying is actually the data that is being used by the application. I've got over 10 different tests required *on top of* the XML functionality provided by Java in my implementations."